# Meu Xamarin só está funcionando na versão debug!

Tags: xamarin, debug, xamarin.android

Durante minhas aplicações, meu xamarin começou a rodar só em debug, quando altero para solução release, ele continua usando o debug. Já tentei reiniciar o pc, baixar o projeto novamente, alterar algumas configs, porém NADA. Alguém já teve esse problema? obrigado.

Comment: Fez a simpatia de são longuinho? Apagou a `bin`, `obj` os packages, fechou o VS, abriu novamente, restore nuget packages, clean e rebuild?

Comment: vou fazer isso aí!